# Explanation of PHP's fflush() function

Tags: php, filesystems

The manual says that it flushes the output to a file. Plus they give an example.

```
$filename = 'bar.txt';

$file = fopen($filename, 'r+');
rewind($file);
fwrite($file, 'Foo');
fflush($file);
ftruncate($file, ftell($file));
fclose($file);
```

I tried to understand its necessity. What I did was the following:

- I created a bar.txt file
- I runned the script
- I opened bar.txt and saw 'Foo' inside it, then I made the file empty again.
- Then... I removed `fflush($file);` from the script and runned it again.
- The result was exactly the same. I made the file empty yet another time.
- After that I changed the `frwite()` line to `fwrite($file, 'Foo'); die();`
- Again... same results... a file with 'Foo' inside it.

Now, I don't see the point of using `fflush()`.

I can't see the necessity of fflush in this example. Can you provide an example in which `fflush()` is really necessary.

Link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php

Comment: If your system is doing any behind the scenes caching, this ensures that the data is actually flushed to disk. As your code **could** be run on ANY system that can run PHP best just use it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly May I know how to turn that caching off?

Comment: You can find out for yourself. But the point is will that buffering/cacheing be turned off on every system that might ever use this piece of code you are writing??

Answer (score 5):

#### `fflush`

For efficiency purpose, core system library of PHP does not necessarily writes to a file immediately when we call functions like `fwrite` or `fputcsv`. It stores them in buffer and stores at the same time after a while.

For eg lets say you have loop and inside that loop you call `fputcsv` function then system library of PHP does not necessarily stores it into the file at every loop.

#### So whats the point of using `fflush`?

But for logging purpose we need to ensure that log is seen as soon as possible therefore it is better to use `fflush` after each `fwrite`. For other purpose than logging we don't need to force flushing. Let PHP internals handle the efficiency.

#### Reference

> This function forces a write of all buffered output to the resource pointed to by the file handle.
>   [`fflush` PHP Documentaiton](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php)

Comment: Note that `fflush()` does not guarantee that the data is physically written to the underlying media. If the system crashes immediately after a successful `fflush()`, then the data written may still be lost. To ensure data persistence you'd need `fsync()` but unfortunately -- PHP being PHP -- that function does not exist.

Comment: @jlh PHP 8.1 will include `fsync` and `fdatasync` functions.

Answer (score 4):

[fflush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fflush.php) provides the same necessity as [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php), the difference being that the output is sent to a file rather than a browser.

Basically what it's doing is forcing data to be written immediately rather than storing it all in a buffer until it is ready to be written. This can be useful in several situations, for example - monitoring logs using the linux command `tail`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_(Unix).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does PHP has a function which writes a string to a buffer but doesn't send it immediately to a file? I tested `file_put_contents()` but it does save data immediately.

Comment: @JulianS All of the normal file operations use a buffer, everything after `fopen()` and before `fwrite()` takes place in that buffer.

Comment: @mister martin: seems like this is disadvantage because it will slow down the disk write operations. Esspecially if I use txt files to write users data and I expect to use flock when writing to disk. So with flock I want to finish the write operation as soon as possible and not to block other users from reading the file.