# Counting hits in file. Count reset sometimes from 0

Tags: php, file, flock

I am counting hits per day in a file, using this code:

```
// Stats
$filename = "./stats/".date("Y-m-d").".txt";
$number = file_get_contents($filename); 
$f = fopen($filename, 'a');
if(flock($f, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    ftruncate($f, 0);
    fwrite($f, $number+1); 
    flock($f, LOCK_UN);
}
fclose($f);
```

I was searching and I am using `flock` as I read on another SO post. But sometimes the current day file re-starts from 0. In don't understand why.

How can I solve this problem?

Thank you!!!

Comment: `But sometimes the current day file re-starts from 0`:- then you have to show how you generated current date file and how you placed counter in that.

Comment: @AlivetoDie The code in the question is the code I use.

Comment: I check the txt file many times a day. The problem is that it sometimes resets to 0. Now it is 3756, after another time it is a lower number or 0...

Comment: Is the server setup to the right timezone? You may be checking it 'later' in the day, but to the server it is a 'new' day.

Comment: @Luke  point is right.

Comment: Yes, the timezone is right. I just checked.

Comment: For example, the txt file for yesterday is "239" (even if at a time of day, yesterday the txt had a number greater than 9 000), the txt file for the day before yesterday is "1482" (even if at a time of day the txt had a number greater than 13 000).

Comment: Should I try to `fflush($f)` before `flock($f, LOCK_UN);`? Could this solve the problem? (I remembered when I was programming in C++, and clearing the screen and printing something continuously, I used fflush to flush the output to make it working)

Comment: If the process is called twice, it might cause this error depending on timing. Example. Process A gets contents, assigns correct `number`, locks and prepares to write and close. Process B tries to get contents but is blocked, so assigns `null` to `number`. Process A writes and closes. Process B writes and closes.

Comment: @Luke Thank you very much! Can I lock the file only for writting (to be able to read)? Hmm... But it seems the count won't be really accurate.

Comment: I will try to open the file using `a+`, then wait while file can be locked, get the content by reading the first line, truncate the file and write the number.

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read more about `Flock` on PHP Official Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php, especially first comments.

While the file is locked, `file_get_contents` returns nothing.

Let's try to reproduce your problem:

```
     PROCESS 1
--------------------
--  fgetcontents  --
--     fopen      --             PROCESS 2
--     lock       --        --------------------
--    truncate    --        --  fgetcontents  --   => NULL (file locked)
--  put number+1  --        --     fopen      --
--    unlock      --        --     lock       --
--    fclose      --        --   truncate     --
--------------------        --  put number+1  --   => 1
                            --     unlock     --
                            --     fclose     --
                            --------------------
```

You can also flush the output buffer at the end, using `fflush`. This function forces a write of all buffered output to the resource pointed to by the file handle. (http://php.net/manual/ro/function.fflush.php and [Explanation of PHP's fflush() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119672/explanation-of-phps-fflush-function)).

I think that is what you need (reading content of file, after locking it):

```
$f = fopen("file.txt", "a+");
if(flock($f, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    $number = fgets($f);
    ftruncate($f, 0);
    fwrite($f, $number+1); 
    flock($f, LOCK_UN);
}
fclose($f);
```